# Ansible: How to mail attachments with files from remote hosts

Tags: email, logging, ansible, yaml, attachment

I know how to email attachments but that is assuming that the files are on the ansible controller.

Multiple times in a day, I am asked to send log files on two different servers to certain people. I would like to run an Playbook that will just do that.

This is what I have so far:

```
---
- hosts: server1:server2
  remote_user: joe
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo

  tasks:
  - name: Sending error and debug logs to Bob, Suzie
    mail:
      host: localhost
      port: 25
      subject: Logs from {{ ansible_hostname }}
      body: Here are the logs that you have requested
      from: webuser <webuser@something.com>
      to:
      - Bob Smith <bob@something.com>
      - Suzie Owens <suzie@something.com>
      attach:
      - /var/www/stg.something.com/logs/debug.log
      - /var/www/stg.something.com/logs/error.log
      headers:
      - Reply-To=webuser@something.com
      charset: us-ascii
    become: yes
    become_user: webuser
    become_method: sudo
    delegate_to: localhost
```

I would assume that my issue is delegate_to. My question is what is the format to include server1 & server2?

Answer (score 0):

Please use delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"